# Does a 5G repeater exist that's wireless and simply boosts the signal in proximity to devices using it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, signal-strength

**PLEASE NOTE: This is NOT a request for a product recommendation, simply whether the type of device I describe below exists, period. Please read carefully before removing to understand the intent of the ask, thanks.**

I recently signed on with **T-Mobile 5G home internet**, and I'm finding that sometimes the signal is just barely on the cusp of "Good"; once below that cusp at "Weak" internet is barely if at all available.

The **Arcadyan 5G gateway** I have is positioned physically as below on a corner shelf as close to the ceiling as I could put it. Yes, it's upside down as in just physically moving it around its current, limited space this seemed to make a difference.

[image: Arcadyan 5G gateway, upside down.]

I've seen various "dumb" 2.4 / 5 GHz wifi repeaters online presumably meant for home wifi which just boost whatever signal. Do similar devices exist (again, NOT seeking product recommendation, just if such a solution is available, period) for the 5G bands T-Mobile uses, in this case,  commercial or DIY? The closest I've seen so far are boosters meant for vehicle or RV or campsite use, where it'll increase the 5G signal locally, is that the closest fit or does something exist I'm currently unaware of to solve my problem?

I'd prefer to avoid a commercial MIMO internal/external antenna setup as of the ones I've seen installation involves cracking the gateway open and potentially breaking its delicate internal antenna leads, which could mean replacing this $370 or so gateway per T-Mobile's contract.

Advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The reason hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic is because the answers age very quickly. I don’t see how this question is different.

Comment: To reiterate, this is NOT intended as a request for shopping recommendations. I am simply asking if such a device that serves as a repeater in the case of T-Mobile's 5G home internet service exists, including clarifying whether existing wifi repeaters that support "5G" include the same bands used by that provider.

Comment: If only the two others who commented and, in one case, blocked my question altogether assuming I sought *product* recommendations seemingly without reading beyond the title, had been so patient and civil! Thanks for suggesting, I'll ask there as well even though it's a lot smaller than SuperUser (which in the past for me has led to quicker answers).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, is there site for mobile network communications and planning (on low level)? IMHO HW rec is not right site because in this question are involved very specific wireless, regulations, mobile communications.

Comment: The answer to your question, yes a device exists, but they require an Internet connection (which meets a certain specification) in order to function. In my case it’s an “LTE Network Extender”. If your current device works the same way as the device I have, the GPS antenna, actually provides accurate timing information. 4G and 5G signals are highly dependent on accurate timing. Without that internet connection the device I have cannot be used.

Comment: @Ramhound, 1. IMHO these extenders are actually active devices like pico cells. So they must be certified and configured for (and by) specific mobile operator. 2. Also with them you are in Catch 22. To have internet you need extender, for make extender to work you need internet.

Comment: @RomeoNinov - I am aware. Other than a 4G/5G Hotspot it’s the only 4G/5G device I am aware of

Comment: Have you tried putting it by a window rather than near the ceiling? Find out where your nearest mast is & put it in a window facing it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Not yet, but I'll try using the T-Mobile app's tower locator feature again to find out the optimal position based on its assessment. Meanwhile I've ordered a booster that somebody on Reddit claims boosts the particular 600 MHz "N71" band used by the ISP, and created a scheduled task (thanks Nater Tater!) to run a PowerShell script to automatically reboot the gateway in the wee morning hours since I seem to have to do that manually daily to help it reacquire a decent signal.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think such thing exist at all because it will extend the range of signal on some bands and therefore will broke the wireless planning of mobile operator. And with this will mess the way mobile end devices select appropriate tower, etc.

Comment: I could see a problem if the device were strong enough to not merely boost my 5G signal in say only one room of my home, but interfere with and disrupt signal for others in my area (and perhaps get me a visit from FCC). 

I was just hoping for a relatively quick and dirty solution where a 5G booster with such a small range, say like 1 meter, would just bump up 5G signal strength for my gateway wirelessly without having to tamper with the gateway and potentially mess it up given the internal antenna leads are delicate (which would be relevant if I were considering an external antenna setup).

Comment: @DarthContinent, the problem I see is you re-transmit/emit foreign signal and if FCC do not catch you planning and monitoring team  will see interference in the network. The things you talk about (in auto for example) are probably pico cells (which are active devices)